# Two results on the limit of $L^p$ norms

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

What's a simple proof that if $f \in C([a,b])$, $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$, then $\Vert f \Vert_p \to \max(f)$ as $p \to \infty$?

More in general, what's a proof of the following result? Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$  a measure space and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ measurable. If $\Vert f \Vert_q < \infty$ for some $1 \le q < \infty$, then $\Vert f \Vert_p \to \Vert f \Vert_\infty$ as $p \to \infty$.

Comment: It's not $\max f,$ it's $\max |f|,$

Answer (score 0):

First assume that $f\notin L^\infty$. Then, for $A := \{f>C\}$, we have $0<\mu(A)<\infty$ for each $C>0$. This implies $\|f\|_p^p \geq \int_A |f|^pd\mu \geq \mu(A)C^p$, hence $\|f\|_p \geq C(\mu(A))^\frac{1}{p} \to C \quad (p\to\infty)$. This implies $\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p \geq C$ for each $C>0$, hence $\liminf_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p = \infty$ but then the limit must also exist and coincide with the $\liminf$.

Not let $f\in L^\infty$. Again, we get $\liminf \|f\|_p \geq C$ for each $C<\|f\|_\infty$ which yields $\liminf\|f\|_p \geq \|f\|_\infty$ using the same method as above.

On the other hand let $C>\|f\|_\infty$ and $g := \frac{f}{C}$. Then $|g|^p \to 0 \quad (p\to\infty)$ almost everywhere and hence also in $L^1$ because $|g|^p\leq |g|^q \in L^1$ for all $p>q$.
This yields $\|g\|_p^p\to 0$ and therefore $\limsup_{p\to\infty}\|g\|_p \leq 1$. But this yields $\limsup_{p\to\infty} \|f\|_p \leq C$. Since $C>\|f\|_\infty$ was arbitrary we get $\limsup_{p\to\infty}\|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_\infty$.

Putting all together we have
$$\liminf \|f\|_p \leq \limsup\|f\|_p \leq \|f\|_\infty\leq\liminf\|f\|_p$$

Therefore we must have equality everywhere which yields the claim.

Comment: @Axel It should be "Now" instead of "Not", that is a typo. Is that what you mean? Because apart from that you can actually copy the proof from above word by word for the case that $C<\|f\|_\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

First we solve for $\|f\|_{\infty}<\infty$. By normalizing, we assume that $|f(x)|\leq 1$ almost everywhere, then $|f(x)|^{r}\leq|f(x)|^{q}$ for any $r>q$, where $q$ is such that $\|f\|_{q}<\infty$ as in your given condition. So $\|f\|_{r}\leq\|f\|_{q}^{q/r}$. Note that we can exclude the case that $\|f\|_{q}=0$, if not, $f$ is just $0$ almost everywhere. So now $\limsup_{r\rightarrow\infty}\|f\|_{r}\leq 1$. Now let $\epsilon>0$ be given, then some measurable set $S$ is such that $|S|>0$ and $1-\epsilon\leq|f(x)|$ for $x\in S$. Hence $(1-\epsilon)|S|^{1/r}\leq\|f\|_{r}<\infty$ for $r>q$, hence $1-\epsilon\leq\liminf_{r\rightarrow\infty}\|f\|_{r}$, taking $\epsilon\rightarrow 0$ yields the first result.

For $\|f\|_{\infty}=\infty$, we may assume that $f\in L^{r}$ for all $r\in[q,\infty)$. Now the function $r\rightarrow\log\|f\|_{r}^{r}$ is convex and hence monotonic on some $(x_{0},\infty)$, hence $\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty}\|f\|_{L^{r}}=L$ exists in extended real sense. Assume the contrary that $L<\infty$. For each $n$, some measurable set $S_{n}$ is such that $|S_{n}|>0$ with $|f(x)|\geq n$ for $x\in S_{n}$, then $|S_{n}|n^{r}\leq\displaystyle\int_{X}|f(x)|^{r}dx=\|f\|_{r}^{r}<\infty$. In particular, $|S_{n}|<\infty$, hence $|S_{n}|^{1/r}n\leq\|f\|_{r}$, taking $r\rightarrow\infty$ yields $n\leq L$, this is true for any $n$, which is clearly absurd.